# Getting a grip on iOS and Android soft keyboard from HTML or Javascript

Tags: forms, submit, android-softkeyboard, onsubmit, soft-keyboard

In brief:

Is there any way to get the 'Go' button in the iOS and Android softkeyboard to trigger a submit event that has been defined with Javascript (jQueryMobile) and that is not represented as the onsubmit attribute of the form?

Let me elaborate:

I am building a cross-platform mobile app using jQueryMobile and Phonegap.

I have a few forms with (type=number) inputs. When the user clicks in the input, the soft keyboard appears. So far, so good.

Now I want the form to be submitted when the user presses the 'Go' button in the soft keyboard. I read [in this Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/2828dc423d526ec6/eb01691a9fca0e7b?pli=1) that the 'Go' button gets its action from the 'submit' event for the form.

However, for me this does not happen. Perhaps it is because I am binding my events using jQuery instead of defining them in the HTML, i.e.

```
$('body').on('submit','#oneIncomeForm',function(e){
        console.log('Preventing default')
        e.preventDefault();
        submitIncome();
    })
```

I would really like to avoid specifying the onsubmit attribute of the form in the HTML, because this messes with the process of Javascript obfuscation that I use before publishing the app.